# jquery select next tag, but not of the same type

Tags: jquery

If I have this structure:

```
<h5>Some Text</h5>
<div>Some more text related to the text above.</div>
```

I know I can select the div with:

```
$('h5 + div')
```

My problem is if I have a jquery Object already containing the h5 tag, is there a way to access that following div?

```
$('h5').each(function() {
    // now how do I grab the div just below it?
    $DIV = ??????????
}
```

<strike>`$.next()` only apparently finds actual siblings (the tags must be the same) so its not any help here.</strike>

The documentation made it look like .next only got tags of the same type, and when I tested I made a different error, so this question is really a non-question :-\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this, you can specify the selector while using `next` so it will look for that in the siblings.

```
$('h5').next("div");
```

Looking at your markup, `next()` will also help you since `div` is the immediate sibling of `h5`.